# When does AWS Elastic Load Balancer returns response with an empty header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, solrj, amazon-elb

When does AWS Elastic Load Balancer returns response with an empty header ?
I am getting empty response headers from ELB, and requests not reaching backend targets.

Comment: Hi @Aditya, are you able to obtain any headers by hitting your app directly without ELB? can you check if there's any info in `curl -I <your_elb_cname>` output?

Answer (score 0):

@marianogg9 yes by directly hitting the target I am able to get headers in response, though sometimes due to some race condition in elb requests are not even routed to backend targets hence generating null headers in response.